# Identify individual sprite from group in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sprite

**Original Post:**
With pygame is it possible to identify a random sprite from a Group?

I'm trying to learn Python and have been trying to enhance the [Alien Invasion](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc/tree/master/chapter_14) program. for the aliens themselves an alien with the alien class and a group is created from this with 4 rows of 8 aliens.

I'd like to periodically have a random alien fly down to the bottom of the screen. Is it possible to do this with a group or do I have to come up with some other means of creating my fleet if I want to have this functionality?

I've came across a few cases where other people seem to have been trying something similar but there isn't any information stating if they were successful or not.

**Update:**
I've looked into this a little further. I tried creating an `alien_attack` function in `game_functions.py`. It was as follows:

```
def alien_attack(aliens):
    for alien in aliens:
        alien.y += alien.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor
        alien.rect.y = alien.y
```

I called it from the while loop in `alien_invasion.py` with `gf.alien_attack(aliens)`. Unfortunately this caused 3 rows to vanish and one row to attack in the manner I desire except that the whole row did this instead of an individual sprite.

I also tried changing `aliens = Group()` to `aliens = GroupSingle()` in `alien_attack.py`. This caused the game to start with only one sprite on the screen. It attacked in the manner I desire but I'd like all the other sprites to appear also but not attack. How is this done?

Comment: If you question is **Is it possible to do this with a group?**, then **yes**.

Comment: Great. Thought I was going to have to start over. Any suggestions how this is done? If you can even point me to a page that outlines how to do this I'd be greatful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick a random sprite by calling `random.choice(sprite_group.sprites())` ([`sprites()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.sprites) returns a list of the sprites in the group). Assign this sprite to a variable and do whatever you want with it.

Here's a minimal example in which I just draw an orange rect over the selected sprite and call its `move_down` method (press <kbd>R</kbd> to select another random sprite).

```
import random
import pygame as pg


class Entity(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)

    def move_down(self):
        self.rect.y += 2


def main():
    pg.init()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    for _ in range(20):
        pos = random.randrange(630), random.randrange(470)
        all_sprites.add(Entity(pos))

    # Select a random sprite from the all_sprites group.
    selected_sprite = random.choice(all_sprites.sprites())

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_r:
                    selected_sprite = random.choice(all_sprites.sprites())

        all_sprites.update()
        # Use the selected sprite in the game loop.
        selected_sprite.move_down()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        # Draw a rect over the selected sprite.
        pg.draw.rect(screen, (255, 128, 0), selected_sprite.rect, 2)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: Cheers. that seems to work. Now to add some sort of timer to have a little more control over it.